# Loop a React-Native UI component

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am trying to loop a button so that I have 6 buttons created on the UI. However, I don't get the desired output, instead throws an error.

> The error: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for

Can someone help me out please.

The code used is as follows:

```
...

  renderButtons = () => {
    const buttons = [];
    for( let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
       buttons.push(
        <Text>
          i
        </Text>
      )
    }
    return buttons;
  }

render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Image style={styles.toast} source={img} >

        </Image>
        <View>
          {this.renderButtons()}
        </View>

      </VIew>

    );
  }
}
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems just a typo on `</VIew>` because of that you are getting

> Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for

Just replace with `</View>`

Comment: Yup. I missed that. But I have one more question hope you could help me out. The button doesn't look like a button (not able to click etc). How can I fix this ?

Comment: just because you haven't use `Button`, its `Text`. You can use `TouchableOpacity` if you just want to click with `Text`